# CSV Module AttributeError

Tags: python, csv

So I copied and pasted a demo program from the book I am using to learn Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
    import csv
total = 0
priciest = ('',0,0,0)
r = csv.reader(open('purchases.csv'))
for row in r:
    cost = float(row[1]) * float(row[2])
    total += cost
    if cost == priciest[3]:
        priciest = row + [cost]
print("You spent", total)
print("Your priciest purchase was", priciest[1], priciest[0], "at a total cost of", priciest[3])
```

And I get the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "purchases.py", line 2, in <module>
        import csv
      File "/Users/Solomon/Desktop/Python/csv.py", line 5, in <module>
        r = csv.read(open('purchases.csv'))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

*Update:
**Fixed All The Errors**
Now I'm getting:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "purchases.py", line 6, in <module>
    for row in r:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

What was happening in terms of the CSV.py:
I had a file with the same code named csv.py, saved in the same directory. I thought that the fact that it was named csv .py was screwing it up, so I started a new file called purchases.py, but forgot to delete csv

Comment: also make sure you delete (if present) any `csv.pyc` file that may have been created on import

Comment: Had the same error, for same reason

Answer (score 93):

Don't name your file `csv.py`.
When you do, Python will look in your file for the `csv` code instead of the standard library `csv` module.

Edit: to include the important note in the comment: if there's a `csv.pyc` file left over in that directory, you'll have to delete that. that is Python bytecode which would be used in place of re-running your `csv.py` file.

Comment: I had the same error. But after I changed the name of the file I had to remove the csv.pyc from the working folder.

Answer (score 3):

There is a discrepancy between the code in the traceback of your error:

```
r = csv.read(open('purchases.csv'))
```

And the code you posted:

```
r = csv.reader(open('purchases.csv'))
```

So which are you using?

At any rate, fix that indentation error in line 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
total = 0
```

And create your csv reader object with a context handler, so as not to leave the file handle open:

```
with open('purchases.csv') as f:
  r = csv.reader(f)
```