# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'reader' online when CSV used inside of a METHOD

Tags: python, csv

When I access `csv.reader` from a script, every thing works well but when I access it from a method inside my class, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'GetInstgramUsernames' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

I have looked at these two similar issues my problem is different

- [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341363/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-reader)
- [CSV Module AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711799/csv-module-attributeerror)

Based on those two links, I have ensured that

- A. I am pointing to the correct CSV libray
- B. I don't have a csv.py file in my project

I am new to Python so it could just be a simple oversight, but I have included the code and comments on what works and what doesn't

```
import csv

print(csv.__file__)
# displays: 
# D:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\csv.pyc

reader = csv.reader(open('D:\\dev\\scrapy\\instagram_influencers\\instagram_influencers\\input\\user_names.csv','r'))

print(list(reader))
# displays
# [['user_name'], ['mensfashionpost'], ['creativefasion']]

class GetInstgramUsernames(object):

    def read(self):
        # same line as above but produces an error
        # AttributeError: 'GetInstgramUsernames' object has no attribute 'reader'
        self.xyz = csv.reader(open('D:\\dev\\scrapy\\instagram_influencers\\instagram_influencers\\input\\user_names.csv','r'))
        print(list(self.xyz))



csv = GetInstgramUsernames()

csv.read()
```

**And the actual console output**

```
python xmen.py
D:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\csv.pyc
[['user_name'], ['mensfashionpost'], ['creativefasion']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "xmen.py", line 25, in <module>
    csv.read()
File "xmen.py", line 18, in read
    self.xyz = csv.reader(open('D:\\dev\\scrapy\\instagram_influencers\\instagram_influencers\\input\\user_names.csv','r'))
AttributeError: 'GetInstgramUsernames' object has no attribute 'reader'    D:\dev\scrapy\instagram_influencers>
```

Comment: Don't call your variable `csv`. That name's already taken by the module.

Comment: OMG, why did I not see that :)   - I come from typed compiled languages and totally forgot that I can just overwrite things like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was similar to the other questions.

I did not have a file called `csv.py` but I did use a variable name called `csv`.

Thanks @user2357112 for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add anything to the object, you need to use `self`.  So, the line

```
    reader = csv.reader(open('D:\\dev\\scrapy\\instagram_influencers\\instagram_influencers\\input\\user_names.csv','r'))
```

should say

```
    self.reader = csv.reader(open('D:\\dev\\scrapy\\instagram_influencers\\instagram_influencers\\input\\user_names.csv','r'))
```

You'll notice that you did something similar in the object initialization (the `__init__` section).

Comment: Also, while this didn't cause the error, you'll notice that you fed in the file name and assigned it to a property, but then when you performed `csv.reader` you actually used the raw file name.  You'll want to fix that, too, but it wasn't the actual error you were seeing.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply, buy I was actually just storing to a local variable, I was not trying to add the result on the class, but instead just use the csv reader inside a method, I have altered my code above slightly so that the word reader is not in both the variable and the csv.reader and I still get the same error